# sshfs-fuse : how to open files on one linux box from a second box

Tags: linux, ssh, samba

I am relatively new to the linux world so I apologize in advance for any silly question I may ask. I have set up some tools that I like to use for programming on a ubuntu box.  Now I have another development box (also linux... but not ubuntu) that I'd like to be "access" from my ubuntu box.  Specifically, i'd like to mount the second box like a drive on the first box.
I've been trying to understand sshfs-fuse. 
Do i need to install this on both boxes or just the second box?
Also, is there another tool (aside from samba) that you can recommend? I will be connecting over ssh.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need fuse on the client machine.  Once you have it (and the `sshfs` tool) installed, you can just do something like:

```
$ mkdir ${MOUNT_POINT}
$ sshfs ${SERVER_HOSTNAME}:${SERVER_PATH} ${MOUNT_POINT}
```

Set the variables to whatever you like.

Comment: so client as in my ubuntu box?  sorry, just want to make sure I'm on the same page. I've tried doing something like on the client... "mkdir linuxdevbox".  Then i've tried "sshfs server: myservername linuxdevbox.  that's giving me an error message that its a bad mount point

Comment: so i reversed it to look like:  sshfs server: linuxdevbox myservername but its complaining about the server name.  says "invalid argument'

Comment: @dot, edited to be clearer.